# VB Setting up a click-through but visible windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a form which is set to TopMost. It is basically a gaming tool which runs in-game and only accepts key bindings. Now, I need to disable all click events in the form and making "Click-through" so that the users will not be interrupted when they accidentally click or right-click the form. If I will not use a click-through form, clicking events will focus the form which shows the taskbar and makes the game slow. I'll just use a key binding to enable/disable that click-through feature. How do you set this in a Windows form using VB.Net?

Answer (score 2):

Override CreateParams() in your Form and set the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

This will give the "Click-through" functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: what about exactly opposite - I have transparent border in my form and I want to prevent any background clicking through that border ?